# Installing facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I couldn't find any other questions on this...so I must be doing something wrong. I have never used NuGet before, so my problem could very well be there.

Anyways, I am making a WP8 app in VS2012. I went Project > Manage NuGet Packages > Online > Facebook. It is version 6.4.0. When I hit install, I get the following error:

> Could not install package 'Facebook 6.4.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the package author?

Comment: On their site they suggested putting a question here :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, for me updating Nuget package installer worked. Initial version was 2.0 and it got upgraded to 2.5. Go to Tools=> Extensions and Updates => Updates => Visual Studio Gallery. There you can see update available for Nuget installer. After updating Nuget try installing facebook and facebook client packages.Hope this works....

Comment: It worked for me I was using older version of nuget 2.0 after upgrade to 2.5 it works fine. Thankyou @red devil

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing means that the package you tried to install for Nuget is incompatible with WP7/8 projects. Look at [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Facebook_Graph_API_in_Windows_Phone) Nokia article that explains how to use a modified version of the Facebook Graph API in a WP7/8 project.

Comment: Then you have some other problem. The latest version of that Nuget package ought to be compatible with Windows Phone (and Store) apps. http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue but, the previous version works fine.
go to tools => library package manager=>package manager console
and type
Install-Package Facebook -Version 5.3.2.0
and press enter.

Hope this will help :)